# The type or namespace name 'Flock' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error when trying this code on my 2D game:

> Assets\Scripts\Enemy Spawn\FlockUnit.cs(28,26): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'Flock' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Enemy Spawn\FlockUnit.cs(16,10): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'Flock' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlockUnit : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float FOVAngle;
    [SerializeField] private float smoothDamp;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask obstacleMask;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3[] directionsToCheckWhenAvoidingObstacles;

    private List<FlockUnit> cohesionNeighbours = new List<FlockUnit>();
    private List<FlockUnit> avoidanceNeighbours = new List<FlockUnit>();
    private List<FlockUnit> aligementNeighbours = new List<FlockUnit>();
    private Flock assignedFlock;
    private Vector3 currentVelocity;
    private Vector3 currentObstacleAvoidanceVector;
    private float speed;

    public Transform myTransform { get; set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = transform;
    }

    public void AssignFlock(Flock flock)
    {
        assignedFlock = flock;
    }

    public void InitializeSpeed(float speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void MoveUnit()
    {
        FindNeighbours();
        CalculateSpeed();

        var cohesionVector = CalculateCohesionVector() * assignedFlock.cohesionWeight;
        var avoidanceVector = CalculateAvoidanceVector() * assignedFlock.avoidanceWeight;
        var aligementVector = CalculateAligementVector() * assignedFlock.aligementWeight;
        var boundsVector = CalculateBoundsVector() * assignedFlock.boundsWeight;
        var obstacleVector = CalculateObstacleVector() * assignedFlock.obstacleWeight;

        var moveVector = cohesionVector + avoidanceVector + aligementVector + boundsVector + obstacleVector;
        moveVector = Vector3.SmoothDamp(myTransform.forward, moveVector, ref currentVelocity, smoothDamp);
        moveVector = moveVector.normalized * speed;
        if (moveVector == Vector3.zero)
            moveVector = transform.forward;

        myTransform.forward = moveVector;
        myTransform.position += moveVector * Time.deltaTime;
    }



    private void FindNeighbours()
    {
        cohesionNeighbours.Clear();
        avoidanceNeighbours.Clear();
        aligementNeighbours.Clear();
        var allUnits = assignedFlock.allUnits;
        for (int i = 0; i < allUnits.Length; i++)
        {
            var currentUnit = allUnits[i];
            if (currentUnit != this)
            {
                float currentNeighbourDistanceSqr = Vector3.SqrMagnitude(currentUnit.myTransform.position - myTransform.position);
                if (currentNeighbourDistanceSqr <= assignedFlock.cohesionDistance * assignedFlock.cohesionDistance)
                {
                    cohesionNeighbours.Add(currentUnit);
                }
                if (currentNeighbourDistanceSqr <= assignedFlock.avoidanceDistance * assignedFlock.avoidanceDistance)
                {
                    avoidanceNeighbours.Add(currentUnit);
                }
                if (currentNeighbourDistanceSqr <= assignedFlock.aligementDistance * assignedFlock.aligementDistance)
                {
                    aligementNeighbours.Add(currentUnit);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CalculateSpeed()
    {
        if (cohesionNeighbours.Count == 0)
            return;
        speed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cohesionNeighbours.Count; i++)
        {
            speed += cohesionNeighbours[i].speed;
        }

        speed /= cohesionNeighbours.Count;
        speed = Mathf.Clamp(speed, assignedFlock.minSpeed, assignedFlock.maxSpeed);
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateCohesionVector()
    {
        var cohesionVector = Vector3.zero;
        if (cohesionNeighbours.Count == 0)
            return Vector3.zero;
        int neighboursInFOV = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cohesionNeighbours.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsInFOV(cohesionNeighbours[i].myTransform.position))
            {
                neighboursInFOV++;
                cohesionVector += cohesionNeighbours[i].myTransform.position;
            }
        }

        cohesionVector /= neighboursInFOV;
        cohesionVector -= myTransform.position;
        cohesionVector = cohesionVector.normalized;
        return cohesionVector;
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateAligementVector()
    {
        var aligementVector = myTransform.forward;
        if (aligementNeighbours.Count == 0)
            return myTransform.forward;
        int neighboursInFOV = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < aligementNeighbours.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsInFOV(aligementNeighbours[i].myTransform.position))
            {
                neighboursInFOV++;
                aligementVector += aligementNeighbours[i].myTransform.forward;
            }
        }

        aligementVector /= neighboursInFOV;
        aligementVector = aligementVector.normalized;
        return aligementVector;
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateAvoidanceVector()
    {
        var avoidanceVector = Vector3.zero;
        if (aligementNeighbours.Count == 0)
            return Vector3.zero;
        int neighboursInFOV = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < avoidanceNeighbours.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsInFOV(avoidanceNeighbours[i].myTransform.position))
            {
                neighboursInFOV++;
                avoidanceVector += (myTransform.position - avoidanceNeighbours[i].myTransform.position);
            }
        }

        avoidanceVector /= neighboursInFOV;
        avoidanceVector = avoidanceVector.normalized;
        return avoidanceVector;
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateBoundsVector()
    {
        var offsetToCenter = assignedFlock.transform.position - myTransform.position;
        bool isNearCenter = (offsetToCenter.magnitude >= assignedFlock.boundsDistance * 0.9f);
        return isNearCenter ? offsetToCenter.normalized : Vector3.zero;
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateObstacleVector()
    {
        var obstacleVector = Vector3.zero;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(myTransform.position, myTransform.forward, out hit, assignedFlock.obstacleDistance, obstacleMask))
        {
            obstacleVector = FindBestDirectionToAvoidObstacle();
        }
        else
        {
            currentObstacleAvoidanceVector = Vector3.zero;
        }
        return obstacleVector;
    }

    private Vector3 FindBestDirectionToAvoidObstacle()
    {
        if (currentObstacleAvoidanceVector != Vector3.zero)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (!Physics.Raycast(myTransform.position, myTransform.forward, out hit, assignedFlock.obstacleDistance, obstacleMask))
            {
                return currentObstacleAvoidanceVector;
            }
        }
        float maxDistance = int.MinValue;
        var selectedDirection = Vector3.zero;
        for (int i = 0; i < directionsToCheckWhenAvoidingObstacles.Length; i++)
        {

            RaycastHit hit;
            var currentDirection = myTransform.TransformDirection(directionsToCheckWhenAvoidingObstacles[i].normalized);
            if (Physics.Raycast(myTransform.position, currentDirection, out hit, assignedFlock.obstacleDistance, obstacleMask))
            {

                float currentDistance = (hit.point - myTransform.position).sqrMagnitude;
                if (currentDistance > maxDistance)
                {
                    maxDistance = currentDistance;
                    selectedDirection = currentDirection;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                selectedDirection = currentDirection;
                currentObstacleAvoidanceVector = currentDirection.normalized;
                return selectedDirection.normalized;
            }
        }
        return selectedDirection.normalized;
    }

    private bool IsInFOV(Vector3 position)
    {
        return Vector3.Angle(myTransform.forward, position - myTransform.position) <= FOVAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the type `Flock` declared?  You will need that code for this code to work.

Comment: yeah the problem was in the monobehaviour name it was different than the one i called in the other script. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was just the name of the script it was FlockScript Instead of Flock by itself. and this is the script that was causing the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Flock : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Spawn Setup")]
    [SerializeField] private FlockUnit flockUnitPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private int flockSize;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 spawnBounds;

    [Header("Speed Setup")]
    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _minSpeed;
    public float minSpeed { get { return _minSpeed; } }
    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _maxSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed { get { return _maxSpeed; } }


    [Header("Detection Distances")]

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _cohesionDistance;
    public float cohesionDistance { get { return _cohesionDistance; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _avoidanceDistance;
    public float avoidanceDistance { get { return _avoidanceDistance; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _aligementDistance;
    public float aligementDistance { get { return _aligementDistance; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _obstacleDistance;
    public float obstacleDistance { get { return _obstacleDistance; } }

    [Range(0, 100)]
    [SerializeField] private float _boundsDistance;
    public float boundsDistance { get { return _boundsDistance; } }


    [Header("Behaviour Weights")]

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _cohesionWeight;
    public float cohesionWeight { get { return _cohesionWeight; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _avoidanceWeight;
    public float avoidanceWeight { get { return _avoidanceWeight; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _aligementWeight;
    public float aligementWeight { get { return _aligementWeight; } }

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float _boundsWeight;
    public float boundsWeight { get { return _boundsWeight; } }

    [Range(0, 100)]
    [SerializeField] private float _obstacleWeight;
    public float obstacleWeight { get { return _obstacleWeight; } }

    public FlockUnit[] allUnits { get; set; }

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateUnits();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allUnits.Length; i++)
        {
            allUnits[i].MoveUnit();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateUnits()
    {
        allUnits = new FlockUnit[flockSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < flockSize; i++)
        {
            var randomVector = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere;
            randomVector = new Vector3(randomVector.x * spawnBounds.x, randomVector.y * spawnBounds.y, randomVector.z * spawnBounds.z);
            var spawnPosition = transform.position + randomVector;
            var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 360), 0);
            allUnits[i] = Instantiate(flockUnitPrefab, spawnPosition, rotation);
            allUnits[i].AssignFlock(this);
            allUnits[i].InitializeSpeed(UnityEngine.Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed));
        }
    }
}
```